# Alterar texto label

Tags: jquery

O `JQuery` abaixo não esta trocando o `html` do `label`:

```
<script src="_global/_js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<label id="precoSedex">0.00</label>
   <input type="radio" name="pgtoTipo" value="40010" required />SEDEX

<label id="precoPac">0.00</label>
   <input type="radio" name="pgtoTipo" value="41106" />PAC

<script>
 $("#precoPac").html = 41.51;
 $("#precoSedex").html = 48.71;
</script>
```

Será por que?

Obs.: A biblioteca `JQuery` esta sendo incluída com sucesso na primeira linha e sem erro no console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente dessa forma:

```
 <script>
 $("#precoPac").html(41.51);
 $("#precoSedex").html(48.71);
</script>
```

Comment: obrigado: cansaço com falta de atenção!